# pyspark max size of explicit broadcast

Tags: apache-spark

What is the max size of spark.broadcast(var) where var is a numpy array?
I saw this https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/SPARK-6235 but it is not clear if it applies to an explicit broadcast.

right now I am seeing MemError trying to broadcast 5G to 120Gb machine.
My use case is that I want to do cosine similarity between two huge matrices.

I want to broadcast one of them.

Comment: Did you change `spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold` to increase the threshold? The default is 10MB @momo

Comment: my understanding spark.sql.autoBroadcastJoinThreshold is more for hinting.
my code is basically
x = broadcast(np_array).
rdd.join(x)

Comment: I did increase it but I am getting OOO, not sure why, I have 10Gb block to broadcast on 128Gb machine, should not be OOO.